# Java―read, process and write UTF-8 file

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, io, copy

I am trying to write some that reads an UTF-8 encoded file which can have encoding errors, process the content and write the result to an output file which is also encoded in UTF-8.

My program should modify the content (kind of search and replace) and copy all the rest just one to one. In other words: If the term to search equals the term to replace, the in- and output-file should equal as well.

Generally I am using this code:

```
in = Paths.get( <filename1> );
out = Paths.get( <filename2> );

Files.deleteIfExists( out );
Files.createFile( out );

CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();
decoder.onMalformedInput( CodingErrorAction.IGNORE );
decoder.onUnmappableCharacter( CodingErrorAction.IGNORE );

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( 
    new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream( this.in.toFile() ), decoder ) );

CharsetEncoder encoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder();
encoder.onMalformedInput( CodingErrorAction.IGNORE );
encoder.onUnmappableCharacter( CodingErrorAction.IGNORE );

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( 
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream( this.out.toFile() ), encoder) );

char[] charBuffer = new char[100];
int readCharCount;
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

while( ( readCharCount = reader.read( charBuffer ) ) > 0 )
{
    buffer.append( charBuffer, 0, readCharCount );
    //here goes more code to process the content
    //buffer must be written to output on each iteration
}

writer.write( buffer.toString() );
reader.close();
writer.close();
```

But that is not working. To compare the files I have this little JUnit test which fails:

```
byte[] bytesf1 = Files.readAllBytes( Paths.get( <filename1> ) );
byte[] bytesf2 = Files.readAllBytes( Paths.get( <filename2> ) );
assertTrue( bytesf1.equals( bytesf2 ) );
```

What am I doing wrong, or what can I do to get this working?

Thanks in ahead,
philipp

**EDIT**

Unless I could manage to make the test work after ensuring that my Input file was encoded in UTF-8, what was a basic error, my real point of Interest and question is:

Does the approach above guarantee that defects in the UTF-8 file are also copied one to one, or does the process of loading the chars into a `Stringbuffer` change this?

Comment: does ur files contain Byte Order Mark(BOM)??

Comment: good question! How can I find that out? The Result seems quiet equal except some characters differ…

Comment: can you use Arrays.equals(bytesf1, bytesf2) in your test case instead of bytesf1.equals( bytesf2 )

Comment: I can, I did, but still test fails…

Comment: grep -rl $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' <inputfile> --> no match, so I guess no BOM

Comment: Are you sure the first file is UTF8 encoded?

Comment: It is a mysqldump downloaded from phpmyadmin and fileencoding set to UTF-8. How can I validate that it is really utf-8?

Comment: Open in a standard text editor, make sure all symbols resolve properly (no random NUL marks and stuff)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I opened the file in subime text and ran: view.encoding() in the console: The input file was in 'Western (Windows 1252)' encoding. I guess that came to happen by downloading it with firefox or coping it with linux. I saved the file again with UTF-8 encoding and the test went green.

Comment: To check if the file has a BOM, in vim you can type this command `:setlocal bomb? `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java arrays don't implement a value-based `equals`. This will always fail:

```
assertTrue( bytesf1.equals( bytesf2 ) );
```

Consider:

```
assertArrayEquals(bytesf1, bytesf2);
```

or

```
assertTrue(Arrays.equals(bytesf1, bytesf2));
```